# JavaScript API for Office - How to use console?

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

[msdn docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.range?view=office-js#load-option-) include `console.log()` in many of their code examples.
I've created a React add-in following their [instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/excel-quickstart-react). But all my  `console.log()` calls are not being written to node console that has webpack running in it. 
How do I write something to the console?

Answer (score 0):

console.log only writes to the containing brower's dev tools console AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I've found is to use [Vorlon.js](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac); and with some voodoo you can get it to print stuff to console. vorlon.js's console - which is a html element in a browser tab.

Answer (score -1):

I use

```
OfficeHelpers.UI.notify("sweet"); 
OfficeHelpers.Utilities.log("sweet");
(import * as OfficeHelpers from "@microsoft/office-js-helpers";)
```

Ole